# How could make dynamically element focus?

Tags: javascript

In javascript when press 'add button', button will be created and added on the list. My question is, how could I reduce code for focus function and make it dynamically? According to the code below I have to make focus function for every single created button, but program should work for every new button of course if does it possible.

There is what I try to do.

```js
var i = 0;

function buttonClick() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = "Button" + i;

  const addbuton = document.getElementById('addbuton');
  const a = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');

  const button1 = document.createElement("button");
  button1.setAttribute("id", document.getElementById('number').value);
  button1.setAttribute("class", "name");

  var linkButton = document.createElement('a');
  linkButton.innerHTML = document.getElementById('number').value;
  linkButton.setAttribute("onclick", "getfocus" + i + "()");


  a.appendChild(linkButton);


  const body = document.getElementById('preview');

  button1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('number').value;
  button1.style.display = "block";
  button1.style.width = "100px";
  button1.style.borderRadius = '5px';
  button1.style.border = 'none';
  button1.style.margin = '10px';

  body.appendChild(button1);
};

function myFunction() {
  const element = document.activeElement.id;
  document.getElementById("output-element").innerHTML = element;
}

function getfocus1() {
  document.getElementById("Button1").focus();
}

function getfocus2() {
  document.getElementById("Button2").focus();
}

function getfocus3() {
  document.getElementById("Button3").focus();
}

function getfocus4() {
  document.getElementById("Button4").focus();
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 120px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 120px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="myFunction()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Button List</button>
      <div id="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="preview">
      <input type="text" for="addbuton" id="number" value="" style="display: none;">
      <input type="button" onclick="buttonClick();" id="addbuton" value="Add Button">
      <p>Active element ID: <em id="output-element"></em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the number of the button as a parameter to the `getFocus()` function.

Change

```
linkButton.setAttribute("onclick", "getfocus(" + i + ")");
```

and

```
function getfocus(n) {
  document.getElementById("Button"+n).focus();
}
```

The new code:

```js
var i = 0;

function buttonClick() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = "Button" + i;

  const addbuton = document.getElementById('addbuton');
  const a = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');

  const button1 = document.createElement("button");
  button1.setAttribute("id", document.getElementById('number').value);
  button1.setAttribute("class", "name");

  var linkButton = document.createElement('a');
  linkButton.innerHTML = document.getElementById('number').value;
  linkButton.setAttribute("onclick", "getfocus(" + i + ")");


  a.appendChild(linkButton);


  const body = document.getElementById('preview');

  button1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('number').value;
  button1.style.display = "block";
  button1.style.width = "100px";
  button1.style.borderRadius = '5px';
  button1.style.border = 'none';
  button1.style.margin = '10px';

  body.appendChild(button1);
};

function myFunction() {
  const element = document.activeElement.id;
  document.getElementById("output-element").innerHTML = element;
}

function getfocus(n) {
  document.getElementById("Button"+n).focus();
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 120px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 120px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="myFunction()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Button List</button>
      <div id="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="preview">
      <input type="text" for="addbuton" id="number" value="" style="display: none;">
      <input type="button" onclick="buttonClick();" id="addbuton" value="Add Button">
      <p>Active element ID: <em id="output-element"></em></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, it looks like you're trying to generate a function for each button. Instead, you can use querySelectorAll to select the container of the buttons, and attach one event handler function to it. This will give you access to the event object, and you can use the target property to access the clicked button and perform any desired actions on it. This way, you don't have to generate a new function for each button, which can be more efficient and easier to manage.